# Edit New and Sale labels on products

Tags: magento-1.7, product, product-attribute

I am really struggling to find the file I need to edit to change the text for new and sale labels on products. I'm referring to the labels that appear on products when you set the new date range or when it's on special offer.

Does anyone know where to locate the file that controls this?

Comment: This depends on your theme. Some use css and images to overlay a banner, others use text which should easily be editable in the .csv files

Comment: I forgot to mention, others may be done via product attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is theme dependant. If your theme is setting new or sale products with a specific CSS class then you can search your template files for this class or any other text with a grep command i.e. if you can see that your new products have a class of newproduct then goto the command line, change into the template folder of your frontend theme and then use

```
grep -irl newproduct *
```

to find all instances of this text in your themes template files. This will help you locate where your theme is rendering this data.

It is however more likely that your theme references another module method that performs the logic to decide if a product is new, or on sale. Then you will also need to look in your app/local or app/community folders for the module that is performing the logic to find where the html is being created.

Hope this helps.